# Trying to get property of non-obJect Custom Module

Tags: 7, theming, comments

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in speakerdetailblock_preprocess_block() (line 42

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs when you are getting language from a non object. To fix this check that whether the node is a object and check that 'language' exists in the $node or not.

```
if(is_object($node) && isset($node->language))
```

Then check the stuff that you are going to do.